# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 10, 82) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training an LSTM network but I have an error of

`ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 10, 82) vs (None, 1))`

I do not know where the error in the input shape is coming from. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
# The next step is to split training and testing data. For this we will use sklearn function train_test_split().
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2)

# features and labels shape
features_train = features_train.reshape(len(features_train), 1, features_train.shape[1])

features_train.shape
```

(180568, 1, 82)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(features_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Embedding(180568, 82))
model.add(Dense(67, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.build()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 10)                3720      
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_3 (Embedding)      (None, 10, 82)            14806576  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 10, 82)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 10, 82)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,810,296
Trainable params: 14,810,296
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
history = model.fit(features_train,
                    labels_train,
                    epochs=15,
                    batch_size=128,
                    validation_data=(features_test, labels_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the reshaping operation
2. Put the embedding layer *before* the LSTM layer
3. Remove dropout after the output layer (this makes no sense to me)
4. Remove the sigmoid activation after softmax activation

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(180568, 82))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(67, activation='softmax'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.build()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model(tf.random.uniform((10, 82))).shape
```

```
TensorShape([10, 67])
```

Change your loss function to `"sparse_categorical_crossentropy"`, as your labels appear to be integers.

Comment: I tried implementint as you suggested, however that leads me t o another error `InvalidArgumentError:  indices[121,51] = -1 is not in [0, 180568)
  [[node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-55-315ed48de10a>:5) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5301]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup:
 sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/4127 (defined at /home/jpandeinge/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
train_function`

Comment: You should look the kind of input embedding layers need. Can't really help you with that here since it's our of scope for this question. Feel free to ask a new wisdom, but I would start by looking at the documentation for embedding layers